# JNDI LDAP Implementation

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I am writing a small program which uses JNDI to connect to LDAP server. As I know, to write a program as this I need to have: JDK which has JNDI API, LDAP server, LDAP service provider interface. That is what I know,but I don't know how to use these components to implement my program. Below is my problems:

1. Can I use normal java JDK to use JNDI API or I need to have J2EE?
2. Is LDAP server a software If it is could you recommend which software I should use?
3. Is LDAP SPI included in LDAP server If not could you tell me how to get it?
4. What configuration I need to do after I'm done the problems above?

I am very green in Java and I am using notepadd++ to write code.
Hope to get the helps.

Regards

Comment: **Don't. Use. Notepad++. For. Java. Ever.** You can not throw a dead cat in a dark room to not hit a free IDE meant to ease the pain. Also, welcome to [SO], please read the [FAQ] on how to ask questions here in a way you'll get useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You only need J2SE.
2. (a) yes (b) no.
3. There is no such thing as 'LDAP SPI'. There is a JNDI SPI, and a JNDI LDAP provider which ships with the JDK, which is the client end, not the server end. This sub-question doesn't make sense.
4. There are no 'problems above', merely three or four simple, questions. You will have to configure your chosen LDAP server, and this not the place to ask about it,